Question regarding the formation of joined interface, visualization with the help of simulation at particulate level
I am working on the micro and nanoscale
in a non-scientific sense; it's like mixing a bunch of red and blue marbles in a jar.
I want to see the movement of molecules across the interface for the input of heat flux or temperature-like conditions I make as the heat input. I am doing the following simulation to identify the type of joint found at the atomic scale. The rest of the physical properties, like E, will be done by me.
I need help regarding software that can construct such a simulation for me.
